# Nginx return GET local IP instead domain

Tags: nginx, virtual-machines, reverse-proxy

I'm using Nginx in a separate LXC container as a reverse proxy for all my Virtuals Machines and LXC containers. When I try to authenticate myself to my website, for example phpmyadmin, or Yunohost, which are in separate VMs, Nginx returns the response from the local IP when the POST is from a domain!

[image: Nginx returns a local IP instead of the domain name]
[Nginx returns a local IP instead of the domain name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovsd7.png)

Here I'm trying to authenticate to phpmyadmin. When it is valid, I have to refresh the page to connect successfully.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     mysql.mydomain.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://10.0.2.103;
    }
}
```

My default file is:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
#               proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;

                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
                proxy_set_header    X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN;
        }

        # Pour let's encrypt
        location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
                default_type "text/plain";
                root         /root/certbot-auto/;
        }

        # On interdit tout autre appel
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Apache is used on each VM for each service.

EDIT: I was using CloudFlare for SSL certification. Now I'm using Let's Encrypt with Nginx, and still have the same problem.

EDIT2: I solved the problem for phpmyadmin by forcing itself to use absolute URL, in the configuration file of phpmyadmin:

```
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'https://mysql.example.com/';
```

But the problem is the same for my other services, in my other LXC container and Virtuals Machines.

When I try to connect to the URL agora.mydomain.com for the first time, which is pointing to Yunohost, in a QEMU, this is what's happened:

[image: request agora.mydomain.com became local IP]
[request agora.mydomain.com became local IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLcPC.png)

My nginx VirtualHost is very simple:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     agora.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://10.0.2.106;
#       return 301      https://agora.mydomain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

When using `lynx localhost` in local of the Yunohost VM, it works, so that's why I think it's an Nginx problem.

Same problem for the forum of my website, in another VM again, using shoutbox, but here only when I try to authenticate in login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is with address in proxy_pass directive.
Use there proper hostname insted ip address or add Host header

with defined upstream

```
upstream agora.mydomain.com {
    server 10.0.2.106;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     agora.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://agora.mydomain.com;
    }
}
```

or wtih just Host header

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     agora.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass      http://10.0.2.106;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that just solved my problem ... I'm really a dick, it was just that!

Comment: Thank you so much. But I don't understand why I don't have the problem on my another server which have exactly the same configuration...
Anyway, that's work :)