# nginx showing IP address instead of domain

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

I have a godaddy A record pointing to my Digital Ocean IP address.

Here's the nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    location / {
       proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:3004';
    }
}
```

When I type in the `domain.com` it goes to the server, but the address bar shows the IP address.

How can it show the domain name?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://serverfault.com/questions/862991/nginx-return-get-local-ip-instead-domain

Comment: Just did. `upstream` doesn't work, as well as `proxy_set_header`. Still shows the IP address.

Comment: This is either your browser (cache?) or the backend sending an IP address iso. a domain name in a redirect, not that part of the nginx configuration you show us.